# How to know which API level I'm building for using ndk-build?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, android-manifest

I'm trying to better understand how the selection of the api level works when using ndk-build.

I know I can explicitly set `APP_PLATFORM` in *Application.mk*, and that otherwise ndk-build will target the api indicated in the manifest with `android:minSdkVersion`, but what if my application's manifest has both `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion`, and this is higher than minSdkVersion?

Will ndk-build target the **targetSdkVersion**? And how can I check that?

In case it targets the higher api level, I guess that I will be able to build using native apis only available for that level, but if I run the application on a device with lower api level it should miserably fail, so in that case I should implement some sort of api level checking, is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this code into your `Android.mk` just after you define TARGET_PLATFORM and LOCAL_CFLAGS

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_PLATFORM),android-7)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS   += -DANDROID7
else
ifeq ($(TARGET_PLATFORM),android-8)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS   += -DANDROID8
else
ifeq ($(TARGET_PLATFORM),android-9)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS   += -DANDROID9
endif
endif
endif
```

Now you can check this defines in your C/C++ code:

```
#if defined( ANDROID9 )
   // do stuff for API Level 9
#endif
```

Comment: nice, thanks! If someone was wondering, I was able to make a test and understand that ndk-build targets the **targetSdkVersion** indicated in the manifest.

Comment: @athos It might have been true at that time, but I doubt it now. If you read [this part](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk#app_platform),  it says "If not specified, ndk-build will target the minimum API level supported by the NDK.".

Comment: It also says "When using Gradle and externalNativeBuild, this parameter should not be set directly. Instead, set the minSdkVersion property in the defaultConfig or productFlavors blocks of your module-level build.gradle file. This makes sure your library is used only by apps installed on devices running an adequate version of Android.", but nothing about targetSdkVerion at all. If what you said was true today, it would be really hard to upload new apps to Google Play, because targetSdkVersion got very limited as you may know.

Answer (score 7):

Use `__ANDROID_API__` defined in `$NDK/platforms/android-<level>/<abi>/usr/include/android/api-level.h`

```
#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 21
// building with Android NDK Native API level 21 or higher
posix_fadvise64(fd, ...);
#else
// building with Android NDK Native API level 20 or lower
syscall(__NR_arm_fadvise64_64, fd, ...);
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

- `Android:minSdkVersion`

The **minimum** version of the android platform on which the application will run.

- `Android:targetSdkversion`

Specifies the API level on which the applicaion is **designed to run**.

- `Android:maxSdkVersion`

The **maximum** version of the Android platform on which the application is designed to run.

Comment: Well, I know this, the documentation states what you also wrote clearly for the java api, but I couldn't find explicit references of the same behaviour for the native building system, especially for the specific cases I mention in the question. And also, I'd like to know how I can check this, maybe from some ndk-build's output, but I can't find how.