# Does android always use the newest API to run an app?

Tags: android

I was messing around with [MeasureSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html#makeMeasureSpec%28int,%20int%29) when I came across this bit of text:

> Note: On API level 17 and lower, makeMeasureSpec's implementation was such that the order of arguments did not matter and overflow in either value could impact the resulting MeasureSpec. RelativeLayout was affected by this bug. Apps targeting API levels greater than 17 will get the fixed, more strict behavior.

So that got me wondering: If I build an app for API 14 but I run it on an API 22 device will it fix the bug or will < API 17's bug still exist on the 22 device?

Comment: try it out. Put some effort.

Comment: I have and it seems to, even still I would like conformation from a more experienced developer. Also, I did, I searched for documents confirming this but I was unable to find one (at least one in a syntax and diction I recognize). More over, I don't see how this deserved a downvote it follows the meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[makeMeasureSpec](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#21028)(API 17<) method's implementation is the following:

```
 public static int makeMeasureSpec(int size, int mode) {
        if (sUseBrokenMakeMeasureSpec) {
            return size + mode;
        } else {
            return (size & ~MODE_MASK) | (mode & MODE_MASK);
        }
    }
```

As you can see it's return value is depending on the value of `sUseBrokenMakeMeasureSpec` which [value is assigned](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#3798) in the `View` class's constructor:

```
  sUseBrokenMakeMeasureSpec = targetSdkVersion <= JELLY_BEAN_MR1;
```

So only the app's target will determine the behaviour. By doing it this way a newer system can maintain compatibility with an older app which expets the old behaviour.

Comment: Addendum: do you know if this is the same for the native API (the ones that are called from the java api)? Also, thank you for answering.

Comment: In theory the target sdk can be also checked in native API, but further research should be made.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660575/how-to-know-which-api-level-im-building-for-using-ndk-build